# Simple javaScript bug in game - Image not moving vertically

Tags: javascript, html

This game starts after user clicks on first image - which then disappears and the game image (div) appears.

I have all the functionality working including score, timer of 30 seconds... But one simple thing is missing which I cannot figure out.

Image is supposed to move randomly in any direction but only moves horizontally. I have implemented move method similarly for both horizontal direction by changing style: left property dynamically, but the vertical change is unresponsive when I try to change style: top.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<BASE HREF="http://my.campuscruiser.com/cruiser/waldenu/tushar.gerg/game.html"/>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Image click Game!</title> 
<script> 

var score = 0;
var left=400;
var top = 100;
var deltaX=0;
var deltaY=0;
var width;
var height;
var interval;

function delayedAlert() {
  window.setTimeout(alert, 30000);
}

function alert() {
  clearInterval(interval);
var game = document.getElementById('game');
game.style.display= 'none';
var end = document.getElementById('end');
end.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("Finalscore").value = score;
}


function play() {

var game = document.getElementById('game');
var firstDiv = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
height = window.innerHeight;
width = window.innerWidth;

firstDiv.style.display= 'none';
game.style.display= 'block';

newDir();
  interval = setInterval("move()", 10);
delayedAlert();
 }

function newDir() {
 deltaX=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)-5;
 deltaY=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)-5;

} 

 function move() {


 left= left+deltaX;
 top = top+deltaY;

if (left<=0) {
newDir();
deltaX=Math.abs(deltaX);
 left= left+deltaX;
}

if (left>=width) {
newDir();
deltaX=(-1)*Math.abs(deltaX);
 left= left+deltaX;
}

if (top<=0) {
newDir();
deltaY=Math.abs(deltaY);
 top = top+deltaY;
}

if (top>=height) {
newDir();
deltaY=(-1)*Math.abs(deltaY);
 top = top+deltaY;
}

 var im= document.getElementById('image');
 im.style.top=top;
 im.style.left=left;


 }

function addScore()
{
  score++;
document.getElementById("score").value = score;
return;
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div id ="firstDiv" style="display : block">
    <img onClick = "play();" src="pics/playgame.gif"/></a>
</div>

        <div id="game" style="display : none">
        <p>Score: <input type= "text" id="score" size="3" value="0"></form>   Game ends in 30 seconds -- HURRY</p>

        <img id="image" src="pics/gameImage.gif"  onClick = "addScore();" style="position:relative; left: 400; top: 100; height: 100; width: 80"/>
        </div>

<div id="end" style ="display: none">
<h1>Game Ended - 30 Seconds up</h1>
<p>Score: <input type= "text" id="Finalscore" size="3"></form> </p>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: for starters, `<BASE HREF="http://my.campuscruiser.com/cruiser/waldenu/tushar.gerg/game.html"/>` should not come before the `html` tag. It will push the browser into quirks-mode and then all 'bets are off'

Comment: Lol, fun game. It is moving both horizontally and vertically in IE 11 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Also, your `img id="image"` has a `position:relative;` style set, but I don't see any parent element having a position that is set (to something like relative to..).

Comment: thanks. I find programming in java easier than front end web programming for some reason.. any tips on how to get proficient in programming on the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `top` as a global variable which is conflicting with the default `window.top` variable. Try renaming it to something else or better yet, don't make it a global variable to begin with. (Also, if you do a search and replace, don't change the `im.style.top` instance at Line 82.)

Comment: +1 especially for the "don't change the `im.style.top` instance at Line 82."

Comment: Spotted that but you beat me :). I wouldn't name a function `alert()` either although use of alert() is discouraged anyway.

Comment: @AndyG, why is use of alert() discouraged? That sounds like an old wives tale lol.

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę: nope, that is what is 'advertised' anno 2013. Most common 'reason' is that `alert` blocks the browser (making it *still* a very useful poor man's break-point for debugging).    However nowadays `console.log` etc is commonly advertised (but that will often mess up older browsers, for which you'd then need to supply a poor-man's console shim). As always: everything has it's place, but you'd have a point when you'd view this as the new (over-generalized) 'table are bad' mantra.

Comment: Cool!!! thanks a lot. changed the top variable name and it worked. Knew it was something stupid.. argh

Comment: @GitaarLAB, ah. That makes sense. I don't like things being discouraged or deprecated, but I'm more than happy to let this one 'slide', as I have been unable to switch between tabs, close the browser, etc because some spammy website decided to give me a no-option alert(). I think deprecating the alert() wouldn't be such a bad idea. I'm sure you have experienced this behovior before on websites. It can be very frustrating.

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę: True. But.. it's often incomplete information/advice that often leads to pebkac.   A simple 'alert fix' could be one line: `alert=(function(t){return function(s){if(t)t=confirm('DebugAlert:\n\n'+s)?1:0;};}(true));` but then.. for debugging you could also change 'alert' with 'dbgalrt' (in the previous code-line) and subsequently call `dbgalrt('your debug message');`.   Also good to know that (in FF) the key-combo [`ctrl`+`enter`+`F4`](http://www.puremango.co.uk/2010/02/break-out-of-infinite-alert-popups/) will kill such an (alert) loop.

Comment: It amazes me how much I can learn through random conversation. :-) Thanks for the FF tip, will come in handy!